# Error when trying to render content to html from python tornado server

Tags: python, html, rest, server, tornado

I am trying to run a sample application provided at `https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/templates.html` using which we can render HTML using Tornado templates. I have two files - `index.html` and `server.py` in the same directory/folder.

index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>{{ title }}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <ul>
       {% for item in items %}
         <li>{{ escape(item) }}</li>
       {% end %}
     </ul>
   </body>
 </html>
```

server.py

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
        self.render("index.html", title="My title", items=items)

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

However, when I try to run the `server.py` file, I get an error in the line `self.render("index.html", title="My title", items=items)` which is as follows:

`IOError: [Errno2] No such file or directory: C:\\ ...(Path of my directory)... \\index.html`

`ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /`

I tried searching across various stackoverflow articles but couldn't find any useful fixes for the same. Another important observation while trying to experiment with the code is that on modifying the `MainHandler` class to below code (as provided in another example at `https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html`, my application works without any error:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('<html><body><form action="/myform" method="POST">'
                   '<input type="text" name="message">'
                   '<input type="submit" value="Submit">'
                   '</form></body></html>')

    def post(self):
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        self.write("You wrote " + self.get_body_argument("message"))
```

I am unable to understand what is the issue behind these errors. Please help identify the cause of the error (especially since I've used the exact code given in the Documentation's example) along with how to fix it.

Comment: Please mention the Tornado version you're using.

Comment: @shikhar Missing string concatenation... can you add +\ at the end of each line in self.write ?